# Creating and training multiple ANNs in a loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I have an ANN created with PyBrain and trained on a limited dataset, so for validation I'm individually leaving one line out for testing, then training on the rest and repeating. I obviously want to create and train a new ANN each time. If I create the net outside of the loop, my results are a lot better compared to if I create it new each time within the while loop. Is this because some weightings are stored in net each time I run an ANN cycle, and effectively would be training and testing the data on itself each time (which I obviously want to avoid)? I previously  thought clearing and creating a new ds to add to net each cycle would be sufficient.

```
net = buildNetwork(5, 30, 2, outclass=SigmoidLayer)
k=0
while k<len(content):
  ds = SupervisedDataSet(5, len(configuration))
  ds.clear() 
  for line_num,line in enumerate(content):
   line=line.strip('\n')
   lines=line.split(',')
   shifts=lines[0:5]   
   shifts=[float(i) for i in shifts]

   output = [0. for _ in range(2)]
   output[configuration.index(lines[5])] = 1

   if line_num != k:
        ds.addSample((shifts),(output))
   if line_num == k:
        testing_shifts=shifts


   """Continue running through content, leaving one line for testing and adding all others to ds, repeat so test each individual line in the database"""
```